# wsimport не парсит wsdl файл с 2 any свойствами в sequence

Tags: java, wsdl

Существует wsdl файл из которого я пытаюсь сгенерировать java классы при помощи утилиты wsimport. Генерация завершается ошибкой:

```
[ERROR] Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
```

Строки, из-за которых эта ошибка возникает следующие:

```
            <s:sequence>
              <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax" />
              <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax" />
            </s:sequence>
```

Если удалить одну из строк с "any", то wsdl распарсится, но файл будет сгенерирован некорректно. Что нужно сделать чтобы корректно сгенерировать классы, без удаления строк?

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно создать файл **binding.xml** и прописать там во что переименовать дублированный элемент Any.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610217/jaxb-compiling-issue-error-property-any-is-already-defined) есть хороший пример.